# Is the subring of a commutative ring always itself also a commutative ring?

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

As the title, is a subring of a commutative ring always itself also a commutative ring?

Comment: Yes by definition!

Comment: Yes, commutativity is a "global" property, which applies to any (all) elements of a ring, and so is "inherited" by any subring. "Non-commutativity", on the other hand, is "local", in that two elements may, or may not commute (under the ring multiplication), and thus one cannot conclude a subring of a non-commutative ring is itself non-commutative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. Suppose $A\subseteq B$ is a subring, and let $\cdot_A$ and $\cdot_B$ denote the multiplication operations in $A$ and $B$ respectively. Then for any $x,y\in A$, $x\cdot_A y = x\cdot_B y = y\cdot_B x = y\cdot_A x$.

I've addressed why $A$ is commutative. If that wasn't where your confusion arose, you should give your definition of subring.